# Creating custom JUnit launch configuration in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to create a custom JUnit plugin test launch configuration.

I have extended the class `JUnitWorkbenchLaunchShortcut` and overridden the method `createLaunchConfiguration()` to write my custom configuration.

```
@Override
protected ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy createLaunchConfiguration(final IJavaElement element)
        throws CoreException {
    ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy configuration = super.createLaunchConfiguration(element);
    configuration.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_VM_ARGUMENTS,
            XMX2048M_XX_USE_PARALLEL_GC_DOSGI_FRAMEWORK_EXTENSIONS_ORG_ECLIPSE_EQUINOX_WEAVING_HOOK_DEQUINOX_USE_DS_TRUE);
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.USE_PRODUCT, false);
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.APPLICATION, "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench");
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.USE_DEFAULT, false);
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.AUTOMATIC_ADD, false);
    addDependencies(configuration);
    return configuration;
}


private void addDependencies(final ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy configuration) throws CoreException {
    PluginModelNameBuffer wBuffer = new PluginModelNameBuffer();
    PluginModelNameBuffer tBuffer = new PluginModelNameBuffer();
    Set<IPluginModelBase> addedModels = new HashSet<>();

    String projectName = configuration.getAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PROJECT_NAME, "");
    IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projectName);
    IPluginModelBase model = PluginRegistry.findModel(project);
    wBuffer.add(model);
    addedModels.add(model);

    IPluginModelBase[] externalModels = PluginRegistry.getExternalModels();
    for (IPluginModelBase externalModel : externalModels) {
        String id = externalModel.getPluginBase().getId();
        if (id != null) {
            switch (id) {
            case "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application":
            case "org.eclipse.equinox.ds":
            case "org.eclipse.equinox.event":
                tBuffer.add(externalModel);
                addedModels.add(externalModel);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    TreeSet<String> checkedWorkspace = new TreeSet<>();
    IPluginModelBase[] workspaceModels = PluginRegistry.getWorkspaceModels();
    for (IPluginModelBase workspaceModel : workspaceModels) {
        checkedWorkspace.add(workspaceModel.getPluginBase().getId());
    }

    EclipsePluginValidationOperation eclipsePluginValidationOperation = new EclipsePluginValidationOperation(
            configuration);
    eclipsePluginValidationOperation.run(null);

    while (eclipsePluginValidationOperation.hasErrors()) {
        Set<String> additionalIds = DependencyManager.getDependencies(addedModels.toArray(), true, null);
        if (additionalIds.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        additionalIds.stream().map(PluginRegistry::findEntry).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(ModelEntry::getModel)
                .forEach(addedModels::add);

        for (String id : additionalIds) {
            IPluginModelBase plugin = findPlugin(id);
            if (!plugin.getPluginBase().getId().endsWith("tests")) {
                if (checkedWorkspace.contains(plugin.getPluginBase().getId())) {
                    wBuffer.add(plugin);
                } else {
                    tBuffer.add(plugin);
                }
            }
        }
        eclipsePluginValidationOperation.run(null);
    }

    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.SELECTED_WORKSPACE_PLUGINS, wBuffer.toString());
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.SELECTED_TARGET_PLUGINS, tBuffer.toString());
}

protected IPluginModelBase findPlugin(final String id) {
    ModelEntry entry = PluginRegistry.findEntry(id);
    if (entry != null) {
        return entry.getModel();
      }
    return null;
   }
}
```

The launch configuration is created exactly how its supposed to be but plugin test does not run when the workbench is opened. The tests are executed only when the run configuration dialog is opened and the `run` button inside it is clicked.